# Integrate Google Cloud text-to-speech into Android project

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, text-to-speech

I have conflicts with class duplication while intergrating Google Cloud TTS (Gradle snippet below). Can't find working solution for this. [This example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/android-docs-samples) doens't work for me, I can't even build this test project. Thanks.

```
android {
...
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation ('com.google.cloud:google-cloud-texttospeech:2.28.0'){
        exclude module: 'protobuf-javalite'
        exclude module: 'protobuf-java'
        exclude module: 'proto-google-common-protos'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider exploring the [Client Libraries with Java](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/create-audio-text-client-libraries#client-libraries-install-java) to see how you can integrate the API with your project. Android also has a [detailed guide](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech) on how to use Text-to-Speech within android systems/ applications.

Adding in some GitHub documents that I found useful for this use case.

- [Google Cloud Platform TTS use API-KEY on Android](https://github.com/changemyminds/Google-Cloud-TTS-Android)
- [Google Cloud Speech API examples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/android-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/Speech)

Comment: Thanks you for research, but this doesn't help to seamless integrate Google Cloud TTS to android project: you will faced the issue that I mentioned in the post